# How to add simulated network latency utilities to conduct live tests

Tags: linux, networking

I am working on a project related to monitoring video stream, I need add simulated network latency utilities that slow down network bandwidth. Is there any lightweight, free, piece of software whose sole purpose is to add network latency?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can have all the variable packets loss, latency, re-ordering and jitter in the netem packet suit. You can exactly mimic the internet delays, duplicates  Jitter & loss using netem suit.

Example command:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 200ms 40ms 25% loss 15.3% 25% duplicate 1% corrupt 0.1% reorder 25% 50%
```

Description:

- latency delay 200ms +-40ms with the next random element depending 25%
  on the last packet sent
- packet loss causes 15.3% of the packets to be
  randomly dropped and lost, each successive probability depends by 25%
  on the last one. (Probn = .25 * Probn-1 + .75 * Random)
- packet duplication set to 1% of packets sent
- packet corruption introduces a
  single bit error at a random offset in the packet. This will affect
  0.1% of the traffic.
- packet reordering means the first 25% of packets (with a correlation of 50%) will get sent immediately.

You can refer more here - [Netem Link1](https://calomel.org/network_loss_emulation.html) 
[Netem Link2](http://opensourceforu.com/2012/06/bandwidth-throttling-netem-network-emulation/)